# Get top n elements from ruby array of hash values

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

Hey I have an array where each element is a hash containing a few values and a count.

```
result = [
           {"count" => 3,"name" => "user1"}, 
           {"count" => 10,"name" => "user2"}, 
           {"count" => 10, "user3"},
           {"count" => 2, "user4"}
         ]
```

I can sort the array by count as follows:

```
result = result.sort_by do |r|
  r["count"]
end
```

Now I want to be able to retrieve the top n entries based on count (not just first(n)) Is there an elegant way to do this?
So as an example, let n = 1 I would expect a result set of.

```
[{"count" => 10,"name" => "user2"}, {"count" => 10, "user3"}]
```

since I asked for all entries with the highest score.. if I asked for top 2 highest scores I'd get

```
 [{"count" => 10,"name" => "user2"}, {"count" => 10, "user3"}, {"count" => 3, "user1"}]
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) to the rescue (as usual):

```
result.group_by { |r| r["count"] }
      .sort_by  { |k, v| -k }
      .first(2)
      .map(&:last)
      .flatten
```

Most of the work is done by the `group_by`. The [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) simply lines things up so that [`first(2)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-first) will pick off the groups you want. Then [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map) with [`last`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-last) will extract the count/name hashes that you started with and the final [`flatten`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-flatten) will clean up the extra left over arrays.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is not elegant in terms of being concise, but it has better time complexity.
In other words, it should execute a lot faster for a very large number of hashes.

You will need to install the ["algorithms"](https://github.com/kanwei/algorithms) gem in order to use the Heap data structure:

[Heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) are an efficient data structure when you need to find the largest or smallest elements in a group. This particular type of heap is [optimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) if the value of "n" is much smaller than the total number of pairs.

```
require 'algorithms'
def take_highest(result,n)
  max_heap = Containers::Heap.new(result){|x,y| (x["count"] <=> y["count"]) == 1}
  last = max_heap.pop
  count = 0
  highest = [last]
  loop do   
    top = max_heap.pop
    break if top.nil?
    count += (top["count"] == last["count"] ? 0 : 1)
    break if count == n
    highest << top
    last = top
  end
  highest
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new_result = result.
  sort_by { |r| -r["count"] }.
  chunk { |r| r["count"] }.
  take(2).
  flat_map(&:last)

#=> [{"count"=>10, "name"=>"user3"}, 
#    {"count"=>10, "name"=>"user2"}, 
#    {"count"=> 3  "name"=>"user1"}]
```

Comment: tokland a.k.a Arnau Sánchez is one of the best ROR Developer I found on SO so far. :) Your answer helped me to get the desired results using ruby hashes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Ruby 2.2.0, [`max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-trunk/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) takes an extra argument that lets you ask for a certain number of top elements instead of just getting one.  Using this, we can improve on *mu is too short*'s answer

```
result = [
           {count: 3, name: 'user1'},
           {count: 10, name: 'user2'},
           {count: 10, name: 'user3'},
           {count: 2, name: 'user4'}
         ]
p result.group_by { |r| r[:count] }
      .max_by(2, &:first)
      .flat_map(&:last)
      .sort_by { |r| -r[:count] }
# => [{:count=>10, :name=>"user2"}, {:count=>10, :name=>"user3"}, {:count=>3, :name=>"user1"}]
```

The docs don't say if the array returned by `max_by` is sorted.  If that turns out to be true though, we could just use `reverse` in the last step instead of sorting.